# SQL deleting connected rows and adding same values

Tags: sql, database

Alright, so I managed to connect these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Artikli] (
[ArtikliId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Naziv]     NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Sifra]     VARCHAR (13)   NOT NULL,
[Vp]        FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[MP]        FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[Napomena]  NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ArtikliId] ASC)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Stanje] (
[StanjeId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Trenutno] INT           NOT NULL,
[Naruceno] INT           NOT NULL,
[Datum]    DATE          NOT NULL,
[Firma]    NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
[ArtiklId] INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StanjeId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] FOREIGN KEY ([StanjeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([ArtikliId])
);
```

And it works like a charm. When it comes to deleting one of these tables rows I did it simple like this:

When deleting Artikl table (ArtiklId and ArtikliId is not a typo :D )

```
 string deleteSql =
            "DELETE FROM T_Stanje WHERE ArtiklId = @Id " +
            "DELETE FROM T_Artikli WHERE ArtikliId = @Id;";
```

and when deleting Stanje table

```
string deleteSql =
            "DELETE FROM T_Stanje WHERE StanjeId = @Id;";
```

These also work like a charm BUT when I add values to Artikli and Stanje and then deleting that Stanje row I am unable to add NEW Stanje for that same Artikli.
[image: Error:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using identity which is automatically generated. so you cannot create the same row.

Secondly, you referenced the wrong foreign key I believe

Comment: Yeah but couln't it be Artikli.ID = 1 and Stanje.ArtiklId = 5? ID's does not have to be the same values,right?

Comment: I fixed this the problem was in the query. But now I have another problem. I can add miltiple 'Stanje' for same 'Artikli'. I added UNIQUE parameter to 'Stanje.ArtiklId' but program runs right pass that and creates duplicates...

Comment: Could you show your unique constraint, or however you did it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] 
FOREIGN KEY ([StanjeId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([ArtikliId])
```

Your foreign key is incorrect. It should be:

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] 
FOREIGN KEY ([ArtiklId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([ArtikliId])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] 
FOREIGN KEY ([StanjeId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([ArtikliId])
```

should be

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] 
FOREIGN KEY ([ArtiklId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([ArtikliId])
```